# User helper functions in Lib classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 3, is it possible to use helper functions in library classes? for example, I have helper:

```
module CarHelper
  def total_price(cars)
    #Do something here
  end
end
```

In my Lib/my_library.rb

```
class MyLibrary
 def myFunc
   # I would like to use helper function total_price(cars) here
 end
```

end

How to use helper functions in Lib classes?

Comment: what about CarHelper::total_price(cars) ? Or CarHelper.total_price(cars), I don't remember exactly

Comment: did you solve how to do it @Mellon

Answer (score 0):

include CarHelper in your MyLibrary class should do the job .

Comment: This approach fails total_price helper calls another helpers. How can all helpers be included?